Relation of improper integrals induced by normalization
Let $f:X'\to X$ be the normalization map of the singular complex curve $X$ with singular locus $S$ and let $S'=f^{-1}(S)$. Then
$\int_{X'\setminus S'}f^*\omega\wedge \overline{f^*\omega} =\int_{X\setminus S}\omega\wedge \overline{\omega} $
Where does this equality comes from? I guess it is a consequence of the fact that it is a homeomorphism away from $S$, but I can't see it formally.
Thank you for any reference or help.
